# IIS 10 , HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: http, iis, server

I m  facing below error on server while deploying /publishing site
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/webtopics/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7

0x8007000d
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: `0x8007000d` is the classic error code for missing OOB components, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html

Comment: Could you please inform us which kind of site(e.g. Asp.Net, Asp.Net Core, etc.) you have hosted on the IIS? I would suggest you try to check the `Web.Config` file and `ApplicationHost.Config` file to see whether there is any malformed XML causing the issue. Try to check whether you are using any Module that is not installed in your IIS, If it is not installed and you are using it in your Web.config file than it may show this error.